# Testing result of Chef FileEdit using ChefSpec

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to use FileEdit to insert a line into a file if it doesn't already exist:

```
ruby_block "insert_line" do
block do
  file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/environment")
  file.insert_line_if_no_match("/blah/", "blah")
  file.write_file
end
```

end

I then try to test this using chefspec:

```
it 'adds blah to the file' do
  expect(chef_run).to render_file('/etc/environment').with_content(/^blah$/)
end
```

The test fails, which I suspect is because `render_file` doesn't support FileEdit.  My question is whether there's an equivalent? Or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: `render_file` targets `templates`, `file` and `cookbook_file` resources according to [this part](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec/blob/ab7a07d60d6df446a3c2063b8825ea8c7bce51b6/lib/chefspec/matchers/render_file_matcher.rb#L83)

Comment: The ruby_block will never even be evaluated.  Chefspec doesn't run the action on any resource, it only creates the resources.

Comment: @tejaycardon I'm unsure, but creating the resource involves the call to the provider load_current_resource or did I misinterpreted the code ?

Comment: @Tensibai I'm not sure where load_current_resource is called, I've never been able to chase that down.  But I'm not sure I follow how that's related to the ruby_block resource not being evaluated.

Comment: @TejayCardon Sorry, was a more generic question not really related. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this in ChefSpec but I suspect that you are correct in that `render_file` doesn't hook into `Chef::Util::FileEdit`.  I would move this check into an integration test using Test Kitchen and BATS.  After trying a few different techniques, I've settled on writing the majority of my tests as integration tests.  When I need to test library code, I treat it as Ruby code and do straight RSpec testing.  It is actually pretty rare for me to write ChefSpec tests now.  I've found that it results in really fast test runs but a lot of duplication between tests and cookbook.